# Get list of files via http server using cli (zsh/bash)

Tags: http, unix, curl, download, wget

Greetings to everyone,

I'm on OSX. I use the terminal a lot as a habit from my Linux old days that I never surpassed. I wanted to download the files listed in this http server: http://files.ubuntu-gr.org/ubuntistas/pdfs/

I select them all with the mouse, put them in a txt files and then gave the following command on the terminal:

```
for i in `cat ../newfile`; do wget http://files.ubuntu-gr.org/ubuntistas/pdfs/$i;done
```

I guess it's pretty self explanatory.

I was wondering if there's any easier, better, cooler way to download this "linked" pdf files using wget or curl.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one line of **wget** as follows:

```
wget -r -nd -A pdf -I /ubuntistas/pdfs/ http://files.ubuntu-gr.org/ubuntistas/pdfs/
```

Here's what each parameter means:

- -r makes wget recursively follow links
- -nd avoids creating directories so all files are stored in the current directory
- -A restricts the files saved by type
- -I restricts by directory (this one is important if you don't want to download the whole internet ;)